# How to amend a pattern with characters at beginning of line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a data file that looks like:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 234 1252 g361
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "g361.t1";
Node_4_length augustus gene 3343 7552 . transcript_id "g361.t1";
protein sequence = [MRSVSLFLLGLAPLL]
Node_5_length augustus gene 334 1252 g362
Node_5_length augustus gene 4543 8252 . transcript_id "g362.t1";
Node_5_length augustus gene 19343 27552 . transcript_id "g362.t1";
protein sequence = [SNLVDWSEPTLTTIEEDTAGMAWA]
```

I would like to amend the text in the transcript_id with the first 10 or so characters in the line (a given file could have >1000 nodes so i need it to capture the entire node number -- but it's fine if it captures some of the word "length"). So for the first set of data above I'd like it to read:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 234 1252 g361
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "Node_4_g361.t1";
Node_4_length augustus gene 3343 7552 . transcript_id "Node_4_g361.t1";
protein sequence = [MRSVSLFLLGLAPLL]
Node_5_length augustus gene 334 1252 g362
Node_5_length augustus gene 4543 8252 . transcript_id "Node_5_g362.t1";
Node_5_length augustus gene 19343 27552 . transcript_id "Node_5_g362.t1";
protein sequence = [SNLVDWSEPTLTTIEEDTAGMAWA]
```

I have tried:

```
sed 's/transcript_id "/transcript_id "SOMETHING/'
```

but cant figure out what to put in the second part of the sed in order to amend the first part with the Node_#### from the same line.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: No one can tell you what you are doing wrong because you did not supply your code. Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first word in the line always ends in `_length`, this `sed` command should do it:

```
sed 's/^\(.*_\)length .* transcript_id "/&\1/' test.txt
```

Output:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 234 1252 g361
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "Node_4_g361.t1";
Node_4_length augustus gene 3343 7552 . transcript_id "Node_4_g361.t1";
protein sequence = [MRSVSLFLLGLAPLL]
Node_5_length augustus gene 334 1252 g362
Node_5_length augustus gene 4543 8252 . transcript_id "Node_5_g362.t1";
Node_5_length augustus gene 19343 27552 . transcript_id "Node_5_g362.t1";
protein sequence = [SNLVDWSEPTLTTIEEDTAGMAWA]
```

Try this if you are not sure about the suffix '_length':

```
sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\).*transcript_id "/&\1/'
```

Output:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 234 1252 g361
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "Node_4_leng361.t1";
Node_4_length augustus gene 3343 7552 . transcript_id "Node_4_leng361.t1";
protein sequence = [MRSVSLFLLGLAPLL]
Node_5_length augustus gene 334 1252 g362
Node_5_length augustus gene 4543 8252 . transcript_id "Node_5_leng362.t1";
Node_5_length augustus gene 19343 27552 . transcript_id "Node_5_leng362.t1";
protein sequence = [SNLVDWSEPTLTTIEEDTAGMAWA]
```

### Explanation

In both cases, you see this replacement pattern:

```
&\1
```

`&` captures the entire match, i.e. everything from the start of the line (`^`) until the opening quote (`"`).
With the second line of your sample input, that would be:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "
```

`\1` captures the first capturing subpattern, i.e. everything between `\(` and `\)`. In my first sed command, that would be:

```
Node_4_
```

That makes the complete replacement string:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "Node_4_
```

Everything that originally followed the opening quote is unaffected, because it is not matched by the pattern.
That makes the complete output:

```
Node_4_length augustus gene 1543 2252 . transcript_id "Node_4_g361.t1";
```

Comment: Thank you! While the first sed command you provided doesn't work (although all the lines do have "length"), the second works well enough. I also appreciate the detailed description.

Comment: Could you supply a line for which the first command doesn't work? Maybe the underscore is missing (in which case we could simply remove it from the search pattern), or it's case-sensitivity, or a tab instead of a space.